# Batch script, re-formatting output of a cli application

Tags: batch-file, formatting

I have a very small batch script which is extracting a quite amount of files.
The script is meant to be delivered with the compressed data to other users.

Now my problem is that this compression tool is outputting a ton of data into the cmd window.
I think this will confuse a lot of useser because the output is really "running". It basically shows a percentage with each line and how it decompressed at which speed (CPU and HDD).
A lot of confusing data that no one needs to see. Now I don't really like suppressing all the output of the program, giving the user feedback on how far the decompression already got would be important in my opinion.
So is it possible to redirect the output and read just the first three digits of that output and deliver that to the users in a single line? So the users only sees an advancing percantage (in one line) and not 20 new lines every second with all this data?

Here an example of how it looks at the moment:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/guTYP.png
The compression tool is SREP, my OS Win 7 x64.

Comment: Name the operating sytem you are running the script on, name the compression tool. You should get a specific answer quickly enough once you do that.

Comment: Windows 7 and SREP but I think the answer from jeb is doing the job :)

Comment: I agree :-D The people on this site are brilliant. Hip, hip +1 for jeb!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple hybrid batch/JScript script that I think will do what you want.

**show3.bat**

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* harmless hybrid line that begins a JScrpt comment

::: Batch part ::::
@cscript //nologo //e:JScript "%~f0"
@exit /b

*** JScript part ***/
while( !WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream ) {
  WScript.StdOut.Write( '\x08\x08\x08' + WScript.StdIn.ReadLine().substr(0,3) );
}
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine();
```

*Usage:*

```
yourCommand | show3
```

The script could be simplified to pure JScript, but then it won't be as convenient to use:

**show3.js**

```
while( !WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream ) {
  WScript.StdOut.Write( '\x08\x08\x08' + WScript.StdIn.ReadLine().substr(0,3) );
}
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine();
```

*Usage:*

```
yourCommand | cscript //nologo show3.js
```

---

***EDIT*** As jeb commented, you should not need any redist to use this solution.

I've taken some of the concepts in jeb's answer and combined the entire process into one hybrid script. No need for a standalone "show3" file.

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* harmless hybrid line that begins a JScrpt comment

:: ***** Batch part ******
@echo off

REM whatever batch code you need goes here

yourCommand | cscript //nologo //e:JScript "%~f0"

REM whatever batch code you need goes here

exit /b

****** JScript part ******/
while( !WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream ) {
  WScript.StdOut.Write( '\x08\x08\x08' + WScript.StdIn.ReadLine().substr(0,3) );
}
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine();
```

`yourCommand` would be whatever compression command you are using. Based on your comments, it sounds like you might have to use `yourCommand 2>&1` if the output you want is printing to stderr instead of stdout.

I've created a "yourCommand.bat" file for testing purposes. It crudely emulates the output behavior you describe for your compression program.

```
@echo off
for /l %%A in (1 1 100) do (
  echo %%A   "I don't want to see this quoted text"
  for /l %%B in (1 1 50000) do rem
)
```

Finally, if you really want a pure batch solution, I greatly simplified jeb's solution. I eliminated the temp file and used a pipe instead.

```
@echo off
if "%~1"==":show3" goto :show3
REM whatever batch code you need goes here

(yourCommand & echo EOF) | "%~f0" :show3

REM whatever batch code you need goes here
exit /b

:show3
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"
:read
set "ln="
set /p "ln="
if not defined ln goto :read
for /f "tokens=1* delims= " %%A in ("!ln!") do if "%%A%%B" equ "EOF" (
  echo(
  exit /b
)
<nul set /p "=!ln:~0,3!   !cr!"
goto :read
```

***Edit*** - *I modified the EOF test to ignore any leading or trailing spaces. This should make the code more robust.*

Comment: Thanks alot too, I will save that answer aswell for a case where I can use something else than batch script :)

Comment: @Paul Green - It's a batch file too! But it's a hybrid with embedded jscript code, this should work at win XP,Vista,Win7

Comment: Really? So the user doesn't need an extra redist for that?

Comment: @Paul - just try it, it should work without problems (most of dbenham's code works)

Comment: @PaulGreen - I've compressed the solution into a single hybrid script. I've also added a greatly simplified version of jeb's pure batch solution.

Comment: thanks alot @dbenham! Working absolutely fine with the edited script.
Took a little time for me to figure out what has been done but I think I got it now, you explained it very well for a noob like me :)
And thanks to jeb again ofcourse.
I'm quite new to stackexchange, can I click anything to give you some points for you help?

Comment: @Paul - I'm glad it works for you. If you haven't already done so, you can click the up "arrow" above the answer score. That awards 10 points, and you can do this for each answer that you think is helpful. The only other possibility - if you prefer my answer over jeb's - is to remove the check from jeb's answer and check mine instead. The selected answer is awarded 15 points. But only one answer can be checked.

Comment: Will do that when I have the 15 points to unlock voting :)
I have one small last problem. It seems like the script stops after extracting the archive. The script needs to run one other program after it's done with srep. I put my "welcome" message above `(yourCommand & echo EOF)` and everything else below that line. Did I missed something?

Comment: @PaulGreen - It sounds like you are calling a batch file from within your script without using the CALL statement. There is nothing in my posted scripts that should cause the behavior you are reporting. I'm curious, which solution variant are you using?

Comment: The last one, that you made based on jebs solution, I first had an JavaScript compile error with the Java variant, then tried the pure batch solution which worked fine so I used that instead :)
I don't call any other batch files :s
Here is the code that follows after the extraction:
`echo Cleaning up
del data.arc.srep
del srep.exe
echo Final extraction
"Arc.exe" x -y "data.arc"
del data.arc
del arc.exe
del unpack.bat`

Comment: @PaulGreen - Make sure there is no space between the `EOF` and the `)`. If that doesn't work, then the only thing I can suggest is to simply try one echo statement after the extraction, and nothing else. Assuming that works, then progressively add more commands until you find which command is the culprit.

Comment: @PaulGreen - Also make sure there is only one space between echo and EOF.

Comment: @PaulGreen - Or simply incorporate the small change I made to the EOF test near the end. It ignores leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: ugh yeah it was a stupid space :)
again, thanks a lot of your help!

Comment: Your version of jeb's script is calling itself without `CALL` in this line: `(yourCommand & echo EOF) | "%~f0" :show3`. I guess, whatever is placed after this line will not be executed, will it?

Comment: @AndriyM - No, the script continues on. A piped execution of a batch file is the one case where CALL is not needed. It works because the batch file is implicitly executed via CMD. So the piped command is really calling CMD.EXE, which always returns, and CMD is calling the batch file.

Comment: Ah, that makes so much sense, and yet I really doubt if I would have figured it out myself. Not too soon, anyway. Excellent explanation, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you use windows batch, it can be done, but it's not simple, as you would normally do this with a FOR/F-Loop.

Like `for /f "delims=" %%a in (`7z packit ...`) do ...`
The problem is here, that the for-loop will first collect all data and wait for the end of `7z` before it process any line of the output.

The only way is to redirect the output, and to scan it simultaneously.
But to do that you need a second thread (at best in the same cmd-window).

Something like this would do the job

```
@echo off
echo start
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if "%1"=="internal" goto :readThread
start /b cmd /c ""%~f0" internal"

rem *** myPacker pack here and redirect the output
del archive.7z
del output.tmp
start "title" /b /wait cmd /c  "%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z" u  archive \tempx\*.rtf \tempx\*.pdf ^> output.tmp
echo EOF>>output.tmp
echo ENDE
:waitForEnd
(
> lock (
  rem
) || goto :waitForEnd
) 2> nul
exit /b

:readThread

for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"
echo ####!cr!x
echo(
<output.tmp ( 
    echo ## before
    call :readData 2> lock
    echo after
)
exit /b

:readData
set "var="
set /p var=
if "!var!"=="EOF" exit /b
if defined var (
  <nul set /p ".=Processing files, currently at !var:~0,4!!CR!"
)
goto :readData
```

Comment: +1, This is impressive... and insane :-) Adding `del output.tmp` before either `exit /b` would be a good finishing touch.

Comment: Ok, I have one question. I'm trying to understand the whole script (I'm still a bloody beginner with batch script), am I right that the first block from "rem.." to "..exit /b" is just a packing process in that case for 7zip?
I will never pack the stuff with the batch so can I safley delete that part?
I tried it with just replacing the 7zip part with srep.exe (my archiver) data.arc.srep, the batch unpacks the archive but I still get the programs output. I guess this because the output of the program is considered as error code? For example I can only mute it with >nul 2>&1.

Comment: @Paul Green - Yes from `rem..` to `start 7zip` it's the packer code, there you can use something like `start "title" /b /wait cmd /c  "srep.exe" .... ^> output.tmp 2^>^&1`. But you need the lines at `echo EOF>>output.tmp` as end signal for the reader-thread and the lock to wait for the end of the reader thread.

Comment: Aah, right. Got something confused there. The del command for deleting archives got me confused.
So I have `start "title" /b /wait cmd /c  srep.exe data.arc.srep ^> output.tmp 2^>^&1` now. But I doesn't print anything atm, I'm sure I'm missing something. I doubt it but just in case do I need to add `2^>^&1` anywhere else?
The output.tmp gets the output from the program so that definitely works.